# Библиотека iTextSharp: Объединение двух PDF-документов в один с сохранением работающих ссылок

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

### Всем привет! Есть такая задача:

Имеется два PDF-документа. Оба состоят из 197 страниц. В первом документе на 1-2 страницах есть ссылки на остальные (3-197) страницы этого документа. Нужно объединить эти два документа следующим образом:

- 1 и 2 страницы - из первого документа (с работающими ссылками; ссылки должны направлять на соответствующие страницы нового объединенного документа);
- 3-197 страницы - из второго документа.

Объединение делаю следующим образом:

```
Doc:= New iTextSharp.text.Document();
ReaderDoc1:=New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(FileName1);
ReaderDoc2:=New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(FileName2);
FStream:=New System.IO.FileStream(OutFileName, System.IO.FileMode.CreateNew);
Writer := New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfCopy(Doc, FStream); 
Doc.Open();             
Writer.AddPage(Writer.GetImportedPage(ReaderDoc1,1));
Writer.AddPage(Writer.GetImportedPage(ReaderDoc1,2));
PageCount := ReaderDoc2.NumberOfPages;
For f := 3 To PageCount Do
    Writer.AddPage(Writer.GetImportedPage(ReaderDoc2, f));
End For;
```

В результате ссылки перестают работать.
Подскажите, как сохранить ссылки работающими. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Irina_1001, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: А почему метка C#, а код на чём-то паскалеобразном?

Comment: Это не совсем C#, его аналог